# Why are (almost) all of my corrected (Benjamini-Hochberg) p-values equal?

Tags: r, p-value

I have the following p-values:

```
original_pval <- c(0.8125681, 0.3411442, 0.317672, 0.3464842, 0.2220076, 0.2576271, 
0.1929609, 0.275641, 0.3180882, 0.1962801, 0.219256, 0.1734164)
```

When I run `p.adjust` in R, I get equal p-values for all of the numbers except one:

```
p.adjust(p = original_pval, "BH")
```

The results are as follows:

> Result:
>
> 0.8125681 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828 0.3779828

As you can see, all of the p-values are equal except the first one. Why is this happening and is this normal?

I get a different result if I try to do it manually! (and I believe I am doing it wrong when doing it manually)

```
original_pval <- sort(original_pval)
corrected <- 0.5 * (1:length(original_pval))/length(original_pval)
```

> 0.04166667 0.08333333 0.12500000 0.16666667 0.20833333 0.25000000 0.29166667 0.33333333 0.37500000 0.41666667 0.45833333 0.50000000

Or perhaps I am mixing up something when calculating BH manually. [This](https://www.unc.edu/courses/2007spring/biol/145/001/docs/lectures/Nov12.html) is where I got the formula.

But my **main question** is whether it is **normal to see many equal p-values after using Benjamini-Hochberg**?

Comment: The manual calculation must be wrong, it does not even rely on the original p-values.

Comment: I find `p.adjust()` to be buggy in that (1) using only the Benjamini-Hochberg FDR adjustment one *cannot* make rejection decisions, since proper use of the method requires interpretation relative to the unadjusted p-values, and (2) the function always miscalculates the second to last p-value, making it equal to the last. The calculations are not difficult to do on your own (e.g., using excel, or a custom-written function), including proper incorporation of the the original unadjusted p-vaue ordering into the rejection decisions.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand p.adjust("BH") returns the lowest alpha (FDR threshold) for which the test can be considered significant.

So, 0.3779828 means that the test will be significant only if you accept a FDR of 0.3779828 or higher. In this case you will have 11/12 tests considered significant, and you are accepting that 38% of these will be significant by pure chance.

Similar, the highest example in your example will only be significant if you accept a false discovery rate of 0.8125681, which is quite high.

p.s. I confess I cannot reproduce it with code, but this is a start:

```
original_pval <- c(0.8125681, 0.3411442, 0.317672, 0.3464842, 0.2220076, 0.2576271, 
0.1929609, 0.275641, 0.3180882, 0.1962801, 0.219256, 0.1734164)

manual_BH = function (pvals ) {
  data.frame(pval = pvals) %>% 
    mutate(BH=p.adjust(pval, "BH")) %>%
    arrange(pval) %>%
    mutate(j = rank(pval), m = n()) %>%
    mutate(BHmanual_base = j/m) %>%
    mutate(BHmanual03 = 0.3 * j / m,
          BHsignif03 = pval <= BHmanual03) %>% 
    mutate(BHmanual04 = 0.4 * j / m,
          BHsignifc04 = pval <= BHmanual04) %>%
    mutate(BHmanual08 = 0.8 * j / m,
          BHsignifc08 = pval <= BHmanual08)
}
manual_BH(original_pval)
```

Comment: In what sense are such adjusted p-values actually p-values?  A p-value is the probability of getting a result more extreme than that observed if $H_0$ is true.  I don't see where the adjustment follows the probability calculus.

Comment: @FrankHarrell in fact they are also called Q-values, or adjusted p-values. You can interpret them as "I am prepared to accept this association as true, if I am willing to accept that x% of the associations I am calling true are actually false positives", where x% is your FDR threshold (or the output of p.adjust in R)

For example the OP is getting two distinct values from p.adjust (0.8125681 and 0.3779828). If you accept that 81% of your results are false positives, then they are all significant. If you only accept a 38%, they are significant except the first one.

Comment: Thanks.  So we should not label them as p-values.